What would be the name of this pattern?
I have a match entity that represent a tennis match, said match can be between two players or two teams. You cant have player vs team, and a player can be in many teams. I've decided to implement this as follows:
CREATE TABLE Player (
    player_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Team (
    team_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE player_team (
    fk_team_id INT NOT NULL,
    fk_player_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (fk_team_id, fk_player_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_team_id) REFERENCES Team(team_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_player_id) REFERENCES Player(player_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Match (
    match_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Participant (
    participant_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_team INT NULL,
    fk_player INT NULL,
    fk_match INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_match) REFERENCES Match(match_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_team) REFERENCES Team(team_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_player) REFERENCES Player(player_id),
    CHECK (
        (fk_team IS NOT NULL AND fk_player IS NULL) OR
        (fk_team IS NULL AND fk_player IS NOT NULL)
    ),
    UNIQUE (fk_match, fk_player),
    UNIQUE (fk_match, fk_team)
);

How is this pattern called? Per my google research it seems like a weird version of polymorphic association, and the Participant table is acting as a kind of junction table of the 3 entities. I'm also wondering how would I represent this on an ER diagram using Chen's notation.
